# 3D AABB Not working on top left collision C#

Tags: c#, wpf, collision-detection, helix-3d-toolkit, aabb

I have a number of axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABB) that I need to check for collision.  If the bounds are on the right hand side the collision detection is flawless as shown below:

[image: Normal collision]

However, if I come in from the "Left side" the collision fails until it hits a much larger object:

[image: Should collide]

This should be a collision but it fails every time. Below is the code I am using for detection.

```
var Collides =
    (box1.Minimum.X <= box2.Maximum.X && box1.Maximum.X >= box2.Minimum.X) &&
    (box1.Minimum.Y <= box2.Maximum.Y && box1.Maximum.Y >= box2.Minimum.Y) &&
    (box1.Minimum.Z <= box2.Maximum.Z && box1.Maximum.Z >= box2.Minimum.Z);
if(Collides)
    Console.WriteLine(Collides+" - "+DateTime.Now);
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with the code.  Any help would be awesome!

Also I am using Helix-Toolkit with SharpDX as the engine for the models.  I have tried SharpDX.Collision.boxintersectbox and that has the same issue.

Comment: Your collision logic looks good to me. Are the Maximum values for X, Y and Z always greater then the corresponding Minimum values for a given box or can an axis be inverted?

Comment: The axis can be inverted and most of the calculations that should be collisions happen on the X and Z axis.  Y is my long axis that the gray portion moves along.  however in this instance it is not.

Comment: For the logic to always work you must ensure that Minimum < Maximum for every coordinate of both involved boxes. I.e., `float b1minX = < Math.Min(box1.Minimum.X, box1.Maximum.X); float b1maxX = < Math.Max(box1.Minimum.X, box1.Maximum.X); float b2minX = < Math.Min(box2.Minimum.X, box2.Maximum.X); float b2maxX = < Math.Max(box2.Minimum.X, box2.Maximum.X);` etc. and then apply the logic on those  locals.

Comment: That was the ticket!  For some reason coming back in Y negative resulted in a min > max situation. I'm looking into the root cause of that but this answer put me in the right direction!  Thank you.